# Read only field access for fields that are required

Tags: field-level-security

I have a "software license" object that should be readable by a customer community plus user except for one field that should be editable.

**Set up**

- The default external sharing setting for the "software license" object is private
- Through a sharing set I've given the profile read & edit rights for licenses associated with his account.
- I've given the profile of this user Read & edit rights for the "software license" object.
- There is currently no field level security set.

**Issue**

I need to prevent the user from editing any other field then an "authorized user" field in the license object. I thought of doing this by Field level security (setting all other fields to read only). However I can't add the field level security to required fields like "Expiry date". **How can I prevent the user from editing any other field then "authorized user" if I need required fields and therefore can't use field level security?**

Answer (score 1):

Quick alternate approach could be to make the field non-mandatory (setting the field level security as per need) and adding a validation rule on Expiry Date field as per business requirement, this may not be very elegant solution but is workable.

Comment: That is indeed a solution, but not very handy :). Why isn't it just possible to have required fields that are read only for certain profiles?

Comment: Equally dissatisfying: Add a validation rule that lists all the "required read-only" fields in the style of: ((PRIORVALUE(Necessary_Number__c) <> Necessary_Number__c) || ...)
 &&  ($Profile.Name = "Customer Community User")